# Format directive or one liner to truncate a long string ?

Tags: common-lisp

My use case is to print a list of lists as a table, with columns of equal length, so I want to truncate long inputs. Is there a directive to do that ? Maybe a one liner with `~[` conditionals ?

The argument of `~a` allows to fill with blanks:

```
    (format t "~10a***" "aaa")
aaa       ***
    ;; aaa       ***
```

a long input is entirely printed:

```
(format t "~10a***" "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
;; aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa***
```

So I'm doing like this, with the help of [`str:substring`](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str#substring-start-end-s) where start and end can be larger than the list without throwing an error (on the contrary of subseq):

```
(ql:quickload "str")
(defvar mylist '(("header a" "header b")
                 ("col a" "col b")
                 ("much longer col a" "much longer col b")))
(mapcar (lambda (it)
          (format t "~10a | ~10a ~&" (str:substring 0 10 (first it)) 
                  (str:substring 0 10 (second it))))
        mylist)
header a   | header b   
col a      | col b      
much longe | much longe
```

I don't expect format to be able to add an ellipsis (`...`) to the truncated strings, but that would be nice.

I didn't find what I'm looking for in the quick reference or [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html).

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I am aware, but you can certainly write your own and use it with [Tilde Slash](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_ced.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There is also `str:prune length string` now, which accepts an `:ellipsis` argument to tell how to cut the string:

```
(mapcar (lambda (tuple)
                       (format t "~10a | ~10a~&" 
                               (str:prune 10 (first tuple) :ellipsis "…")
                               (str:prune 10 (second tuple) :ellipsis "…")))
                     mylist)
header a   | header b  
col a      | col b     
much long… | much long…
```

we can use the `v` directive to not repeat the column length that much:

```
(defparameter *col-length* 10)

(mapcar (lambda (tuple)
           (format t "~va | ~va~&" 
                     *COL-LENGTH*
                     (str:prune *COL-LENGTH* (first tuple) :ellipsis "…")
                     *COL-LENGTH*
                     (str:prune *COL-LENGTH* (second tuple) :ellipsis "…")))
       mylist)
header a   | header b  
col a      | col b     
much long… | much long…
```

and we could use `(let ((str:*ellipsis* "…") …)`.